# Could I write the following query without the while loop and improve efficiency?

Tags: sql-server

Is there another way that I could do the following query

```
SELECT @MinID = MIN(ID), @MaxID = MAX(ID)
FROM #stp

WHILE (@MinID <= @MaxID AND IsNull(@MaxID, 0) > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT @result_mstr_id = result_mstr_id
    FROM #stp
    WHERE ID = @MinID

    EXECUTE @err = f_rslm_publish @result_mstr_id

    UPDATE dbo.results
       SET result_stat_cd = CASE result_stat_cd
                                WHEN 'IP' THEN 'C'
                                WHEN 'IS' THEN 'S'
                                ELSE result_stat_cd
                            END
     WHERE result_mstr_id = @result_mstr_id

    SELECT @MinID = @MinID + 1

END
```

Its the typical loop being fed by a counter but could I re-write this to be one query?

Comment: What does `f_rslm_publish` do?

Comment: Your example code could have been much simpler. The `IF @@error != 0 GOTO ERROR` statements are irrelevant and distracting. And the `UPDATE` query seems irrelevant too. It would be nice if you edited the title of your question to indicate that a key element of your scenario is that you're executing a stored procedure for multiple values stored in the column of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you need to execute the stored procedure `f_rslm_publish` for every ID in the table `#stp`, then you'll need to use a `WHILE` loop or a cursor.

Unless of course you can change the definition of the stored procedure `f_rslm_publish`, in which case it very well may be possible to rewrite it to accept a range of ID values (and possibly without also adding `WHILE` loops to the stored procedure code).

Comment: I think thats the key - to change the result publish to accept a range of ids

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE result_mstr_id between @MinId and @Maxid
```

Comment: How does that replace the `WHILE` loop for the statement `EXECUTE @err = f_rslm_publish @result_mstr_id`?